# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find any css element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am writing Capybara tests and one of the test case is to "Delete" a post
and I am getting this error constantly. Any help?

```
 Failure/Error:
   within "#post_#{post.id}" do
    click_link 'Delete'
   end

 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#post_8"
```

Code

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "Deleting a Post" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:blog) { FactoryGirl.create(:blog, user: user) }
    let(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, blog: blog) }

    before do
        visit new_user_session_path

        fill_in('Email', with: user.email)
        fill_in('Password', with: user.password)

        click_on("Log in")
    end

    scenario "should delete a post" do

        visit posts_path(blog.url_slug)

        within "#post_#{post.id}" do #### Not able to find this element
            click_link 'Delete'
        end

        expect(page).not_to have_content(page.title)
        expect(Post.count).to eq(0)

    end

end
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <div class="well well-lg">
            <div class="row" id="<%= dom_id(post) %>" >
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <%= image_tag @blog.user.gravatar(100) %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <h2>
                            <%= link_to post.title, "#" %>
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            <%= @redcarpet.render(post.content).html_safe %>
                        </p>
                        <% if @user_have_access %>
                            <%= link_to edit_post_path(@blog.url_slug, post.id), id: post.id do %>
                                Edit
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil space"></span>
                            <% end %>
                            <%= link_to delete_post_path(@blog.url_slug, post.id), method: :delete, 
                                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
                                Delete
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash space"></span>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                        <%= link_to comments_path(@blog.url_slug, post.id) do %>
                            Comments
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.3.1"

gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem "figaro"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'puma'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'rails_12factor'

group :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :development do

  gem 'pry'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'capybara'

end
```

When I try to take a screenshot using `save_and_open_screenshot`, I get the following error

```
Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError Exception: Capybara::Driver::Base#save_screenshot
```

Here is the screenshot of my DOM

[image]

Comment: What does `dom_id(post)` return? Is #post_8 available?

Comment: yes, it is available.

Comment: `<div class="row" id="<%= dom_id(post) %>" >` should it not be: `<div class="row" id="<%= "post_#{post.id}" %>" >`

Comment: I tried both, I get the same error for both. It's not able to find any DOM element, I tried finding other elements but nothing was found.

Comment: Do you have duplicate `id`s in the html on the same page?

Comment: ok I think your syntax for `within` is wrong, try `within(:css, "#post_8")`

Comment: I don't see any duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you on the right path?

Comment: All my other tests are passing, However this is my only test where it's using within block. So I think I am on the right path, however, I might have missed some Capybara configuration

Comment: Are you actually catching the prompt? `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` might that be the problem?

Comment: In order to catch the prompt, I need to click the Delete button first and it's not even identifying that element correctly.

Comment: Post your capybara configurations, save_and_open_page is not working and you need to fix that first. You need to inspect the HTML that capybara is getting.

Answer (score 1):

So I found what the problem is. The PostsController#index is being called before the creation of post. Hence the DOM is not populated and it was not able to find the elements. After I moved the creation inside the scenario block. It started working as expected.

```
    require 'rails_helper'

feature "Deleting a Post" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:blog) { FactoryGirl.create(:blog, user: user) }
    let(:post) {FactoryGilr.create(:post, blog: blob} ### This doesn't create post yet. I am not sure why.

    before do
        visit new_user_session_path

        fill_in('Email', with: user.email)
        fill_in('Password', with: user.password)

        click_on("Log in")
    end

    scenario "should delete a post" do

        ### If I put my post creation here, it does work though.
        post = FactoryGirl.create(:post, blog: blog)

        visit posts_path(blog.url_slug)

        within "#post_#{post.id}" do
            click_link 'Delete'
        end

        expect(page).not_to have_content(post.title)
        expect(Post.count).to eq(0)

    end

end
```

Comment: This is because you're using `let` which is lazyily evaluated, meaning post isn't created until you use the variable.  That means, in your usage,  the post wouldn't be created until after the page is rendered.  If you use `let!` it would be created at declaration time

Comment: You wrote FactoryGilr instead FactoryGirl

Answer (score 1):

`let` lazily defines variables, which means the value isn't actually set (and in this case the Post object) until its first use.  In your case the first use isn't until the `within` statement, which means the record isn't created until after the page is rendered (during the visit call) and therefore the item isn't actually on the page.  If you need the record to be available from the time you define it you should use `let!`.

The reason for the NotSupportedByDriver exception is that you are using the default rack-test driver which has no concept of screen (and no support for JS) and no real CSS support and therefore doesn't implement screenshot